# read epub with nov

Tags: files

Upon reading epub on emacs, I tried https://github.com/wasamasa/nov.el.

Installed and configured step by step as its instructions.

When C-x C-f to open an epub, it is displayed as

```
M Filemode      Length  Date         Time      File
- ----------  --------  -----------  --------  -------------------------------------------
  -rw-rw-rw-        20  17-Apr-2019  15:56:18  mimetype
  -rw-rw-rw-     17950  17-Apr-2019  15:56:20  OEBPS/assets/dsf2_1607.png
  -rw-rw-rw-     27202  17-Apr-2019  15:56:20  OEBPS/assets/dsf2_1603.png
  -rw-rw-rw-     26145  17-Apr-2019  15:56:20  OEBPS/assets/dsf2_1602.png
  -rw-rw-rw-     59360  17-Apr-2019  15:56:18  OEBPS/ch07.html
  -rw-rw-rw-     45564  17-Apr-2019  15:56:20  OEBPS/assets/dsf2_1801.png
  -rw-rw-rw-     55767  17-Apr-2019  15:56:20  OEBPS/assets/dsf2_1202.png
  -rw-rw-rw-     15460  17-Apr-2019  15:56:20  OEBPS/content.opf
  -rw-rw-rw-     41249  17-Apr-2019  15:56:20  OEBPS/assets/dsf2_0503.png
  -rw-rw-rw-    110635  17-Apr-2019  15:56:20  OEBPS/ix01.html
```

Recall the instruction,  I cannot follow the sentence.

```
  You'll also need an Emacs compiled with libxml2 support, otherwise rendering will fail.
```

What does compiled with ... support?

Does it mean that if you want this tiny dispensable function, than have to take risks  to reinstall emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  `M-x nov-mode` to turn it on before you decide it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Re-compiling emacs may not be necessary if your libxml is in a standard location by pk-config. Have you actually tried to use nov.el and does it fail? If libxml is in a non-standard location then you use LIBXML2_LIBS flag to specify where it is. See ./configure --help.